# Node.js, Express not routing parameterized GET request

Tags: node.js, express, routes, get

I'm learning how to use node.js and express following a guide, but can't seem to get part of it to work, even with identical code.

```
app.get('api/courses/:id', (req, res) =>
{
    var courseCode = req.params.id;
    console.log(`Received GET request for ${req.url}`);
    //more code after this..
});
```

But none of the code ever runs - nothing is logged to the console when I use Insomnia to request /api/courses/54, or any other numbers and strings I've tried. My other code works, a GET request for /api/courses. But running this one just returns "Cannot GET /api/courses/54" and logs nothing.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: show all registered routes related to `api/courses`

Comment: All I've got are the above paramaterized one, and

`app.get('/api/catalog', (req, res) =>{ //code here}`

which works
@Anatoly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `/` at the beginning of your path. So, it should be as follow:

```
app.get('/api/courses/:id', (req, res) => {
    var courseCode = req.params.id;
    console.log(`Received GET request for ${req.url}`);
    //more code after this..
});
```